# Java - make static nested class visible to all, but only constructed by parent and subclasses of parent

Tags: java, inner-classes, access-modifiers

I have a parent class containing a struct-like static nested class. The nested class must be public, as it should be returned to other classes where its contents are acted upon. However, only the parent class *and its subclasses* should be able to instantiate the nested class, as they know how to define its contents. All classes shown below are in different packages.

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    public static class Data
    {
        public final String data1
        ...

        public Data(String d1, ...)
        {
            data1 = d1;
            ...
        }
    }

    public abstract Data getData();
}
```

---

```
public final class Subclass extends Parent
{
    @Override
    public Data getData()
    {
        return new Data(.....);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
        final Data d = new Subclass().getData();
        System.out.println(d.data1);
    }
}
```

Declaring the `Data` class `protected` would stop `getData()` from working properly. Decreasing the access modifier on the constructor of `Data` would prevent subclasses of `Parent` from working properly. What I want is something like `protected-by-parent`, which I am guessing does not exist in Java.

Is there a suitable workaround? One possibility I can see is creating a `protected` method in `Parent` that effectively mirrors, calls, and returns from the constructor of `Data` (which would be made `private`). This however seems a bit messy; does anybody know of a better way/design?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot make a constructor of a static member class `protected` for the subclasses of the outer class. That expressiveness doesn't directly exist in the Java language.

But, you can make the constructor of the static member class `Data` `private` - in that case, the outer class can still access it. And the outer class can define a protected factory method that invokes the `Data` constructor - by making it `protected`, it is only accessible to Parent itself, subclasses, and all classes in the same package (as is always the case for the `protected` modifier)

```
public abstract class Parent
{
    protected static Data createData(String d1, ...) {
        return new Data(d1, ...);
    }

    public static class Data
    {
        public final String data1
        ...

        private Data(String d1, ...)
        {
            data1 = d1;
            ...
        }
    }

    public abstract Data getData();
}
```

Comment: This is literally what I suggest in the final paragraph of the question. Thank you for providing an example, however.

Comment: I see that now. Why would you call that "messy" ?

Comment: I suppose messy is not the correct word. What I meant is that it seems like a bit of a bad-style awkward hack, although perhaps it is fine. Looking at the other solution involving a protected implementation of a public interface, this actually seems less "messy". Can anyone comment on merits and drawbacks of either?

Comment: Without further evidence for the other method being better, I'm marking this one as the accepted answer, as it is the one I am currently using.

Answer (score 3):

A better solution would be to make the nested class `protected`, and make it implement a `public` interface. Only the interface will be exposed to outside classes, and the nested class itself will remain an implementation detail.

```
public abstract class Parent
{

    public interface Data {
        public String getData1();
    }

    protected static class DataImpl implements Data
    {
        private final String data1;
        ...

        protected DataImpl(String d1, ...)
        {
            data1 = d1;
            ...
        }
        public String getData1(){
            return data1;
        }
    }

    public abstract Data getData();
}

public final class Subclass extends Parent
{
    @Override
    public Data getData()
    {
        return new DataImpl(.....);
    }
}

public class SomeOtherClass
{
    public void someMethod()
    {
        final Data d = new Subclass().getData();
        System.out.println(d.getData1());
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks good. It *seems* inherently more like clever OOP design, but I struggle to see where it actually improves on the proposed solution in terms of functionality. Could you please expand on *why* this is a better solution?

Comment: @ChristopherRiches It allows you to hide the nested class (which I renamed to `DataImpl`) from `SomeOtherClass`, which prevents `SomeOtherClass` from creating instances of that class, while still allowing `SomeOtherClass` to access the contents of `Data` instances (via the interface). I edited the answer to make the `DataImpl` constructor `protected` too.

Comment: My point is: the protected factory method also achieves this with far less code. Is there anything your method does beyond that?